# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS, even Avast is not installed

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting this error while running avd in Eclipse.

```
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPUS.
```

Most of the solutions I've found on Stack Overflow are related to Avast antivirus, but I'm not using any antivirus program on my PC except Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: Cleaned up formatting & usage errors.

Comment: I just worked out by un-installing the android SDK tools 24.1.2 and the install it again from Android SDK Manager. :)